Topic: Preload Warning for Unused CSS in Next.js Application
This Nextjs Code giving me an Error:
My code is using Shadcn for Ui and Convex as a backend.
My folder structure is as follow:

and my main layout file is as follow:
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import "./globals.css";
import ConvexClientProvider from "../providers/ConvexClientProvider";
import { Toaster } from "@/components/ui/sonner";
import { ModalProvider } from "@/providers/modal-provider";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"], preload: true });

export const metadata: Metadata = ({
  title: "Create Next App",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
});

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <ConvexClientProvider>
          <Toaster />
          <ModalProvider />
          {children}
        </ConvexClientProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

and my Dashboard layout file is as follow:
import { Navbar } from "./_components/Navbar";
import { OrgSidebar } from "./_components/Org-Sidebar";
import Sidebar from "./_components/sidebar";

interface DashboardLayoutProps {
    children: React.ReactNode;
}

const DashboardLayout = ({
    children,
}: DashboardLayoutProps) => {
    return (
        <main className="h-full">
            <Sidebar />
            <div className="pl-[60px] h-full">
                <div className="flex gap-x-3 h-full">
                    <OrgSidebar />
                    <div className="h-full flex-1">
                        <Navbar />
                        {children}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
    )
}

export default DashboardLayout;

My Code is Showing me only white screen and only one warning as follow
error is : "The resource http://localhost:3000/%5C_next/static/css/app/(dashboard)/layout.css?v=1719131483630 was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally."
I want to remove this error and make my code work
Currently showing Loading Icon but not showing after that no any error but displaying white display.

I think the warning you're seeing about prefetching is unrelated to your blank page. Can you share more context about your loading state? Double check that the console in your browser isn't showing any errors.
Regarding the prefetch warning: this is a known and open issue as of June 24 2024 (see this Github discussion on the official NextJS repo). You can read about different solutions people have tried – some of which have worked, many that haven't – for folks who are experiencing the same warning. Maybe one of those solutions will work for you.
The good news is that you're not doing anything wrong as far as the css is going.

This Issue is auto resolve but, I get some new errors as follow: 1:warn-once.ts:6 Image with src "http://localhost:3000/_next/static/media/logo.1fc52fb8.svg" has either width or height modified, but not the other. If you use CSS to change the size of your image, also include the styles 'width: "auto"' or 'height: "auto"' to maintain the aspect ratio.

2:http://localhost:3000/_next/static/css/app/(dashboard)/layout.css?v=1719771050229 was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate as value and it is preloaded intentionally.
